# ls: /storage/emulated: Permission denied

Tags: adb, permissions, shell

List all directory in `storage` with adb :

```
adb shell ls -a   /storage
.
..
emulated
sdcard0
self
```

I want to list all directory located in  `/storage/emulated`:

```
adb shell ls -a   /storage/emulated
ls: /storage/emulated: Permission denied
```

Add `sudo` to list again:

```
sudo adb shell ls -a   /storage/emulated
ls: /storage/emulated: Permission denied
```

How can i get the permission then?

Comment: Is the device rooted? You have use `sudo` but you have not indicated if the device is rooted.

Comment: How to root my android phone?

Comment: `sudo` on host side is pointless, `adb` binary is already running with sufficient permissions