# How can one list all large files?

Tags: file-system, shell

One can list all directories on `/mnt` using:

```
adb shell ls /mnt
```

How can one list all files which are larger than 100M in the directory `/mnt`?

```
 adb shell find -size +10M ;
 sudo adb shell find -size +10M ;
```

Both the above command encounter permission issue such as

```
find: ./dev/socket/property_service: Permission denied
find: No ./dev/pts: Permission denied
```

Comment: Most Android systems have the Linux command `find` which can list files and filter for files based on their size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find files greater than x kB/MB/GB in size, and also show their size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666685/find-files-greater-than-x-kb-mb-gb-in-size-and-also-show-their-size)

Comment: 10M is not 100M. your edit reflect another unrelated question. [first](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/241358/2) question was about list large files. [second](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233558/ls-storage-emulated-permission-denied#comment309164_233558) question is about root access. use `find -H /sdcard`